# Magento 2 error 500 after adding a module

Tags: magento2, setup-script, http-error-500

I added a module by these command

```
php bin/magento module:status
php bin/magento module:enable module
```

Everything was fine then I run this

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

After this everything messed up,
The output of this command is

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
Cache cleared successfully
File system cleanup:
/home/xyz/public_html/var/generation/Composer
/home/xyz/public_html/var/generation/Magento
/home/xyz/public_html/var/generation/Symfony
The directory '/home/xyz/public_html/var/di/' doesn't exist - skipping cleanup
Updating modules:
Schema creation/updates:
```

And after the execution of this command My site returning HTTP ERROR 500.

Any Idea how to solve this ??

Answer (score 2):

Enable the **developer mode**. By running the below commend.

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

after that you can see the errors trace in frontend.

Answer (score 0):

For the unexpected 500 error, we should enable error reporting on the bootstrap. Should enable error reporting with -1 value. That will report all PHP errors.

*app/bootstrap.php*

```
ini_set('display_errors', -1) // Should enable error reporting with -1 value.
```